# In Node.js, how do I chain asynchronous functions sequentially using node-seq?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Today I have been playing with @substack's node-seq module, it allows me to chain together async functions.

https://github.com/substack/node-seq

I got it working with parallel functions, but having trouble running functions sequentially. Whenever I run the following code, it only prints out the 'hello1' statement. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
var Seq = require('seq');

Seq()
    .seq(function () {
        console.log('hello1');
    })
    .seq(function () {
        console.log('hello2');
    })
;
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to [**read the documentation**](https://github.com/substack/node-seq)

> Each method executes callbacks with a context (its `this`) described in the next section. Every method returns `this`.
>
> Whenever `this()` is called with a non-falsy first argument, the error value propagates down to the first `catch` it sees, skipping over all actions in between. There is an implicit `catch` at the end of all chains that prints the error stack if available and otherwise just prints the error.

`this` should solve your problem.

```
var Seq = require('seq');

Seq()
    .seq(function () {
        console.log('hello1');
        this();
    })
    .seq(function () {
        console.log('hello2');
    })
;
```

Otherwise `Seq` has no way of knowing when the step is done.