# How do I pass a variable to the next .seq using Seq?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm working to refactor some Node.js code that uses [Seq](https://github.com/substack/node-seq), and from the documentation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714442/1080402), I get that I use `this()` to move on to the next `.seq()`, but how do I pass a variable to the next `.seq()`'s function?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
$()
.seq(function() {
    User.findById(req.user._id, this);
})
.seq(function(user) {

    if (!user) { return res.json(400, {'user': 'User not found.'} ); }

    var data = req.body;

    saveData(data, user, true);

    this();

})
.seq(function(data) {

    return res.json(data);

})
.catch(next);
```

The first `.seq()` moves right on without any `this()` call, but the second `.seq()` won't move to the next one unless I call `this()`. However, upon reaching the last `.seq`, `data` is now `undefined`. Therefore, I tried this:

```
[...]

    saveData(data, user, true);

    this(data); //Added "data" here

[...]
```

But that, instead, results in an error (I haven't been able to track down what sort of error yet, though, because it somehow gets sent to an errorhandler function that seems to hide the error). How should I be going about this?

Comment: Given that `this` seems to be a nodeback, try `this(null, data)`. But if `saveData` is not async at all, there's no reason to put `res.json(data)` in its own callback.

Comment: That worked! Didn't solve my problem directly, but it led to a chain that fixed it. :) If you put that as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: done… Notice if you found the solution yourself, you can [post an answer yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer); especially if it's more complete

Comment: Yeah, I would, but the actual problem isn't really related to what I asked, so your answer is perfect within the context of the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that callback is not asynchronous, there's no reason to put it in its own `seq` call. Just do

```
…
.seq(function(user) {
    if (!user) 
        return res.json(400, {'user': 'User not found.'} );
    var data = req.body;
    saveData(data, user, true);
    return res.json(data);
})
```

Otherwise, if you really need to pass through the data, `this` does adhere to node callback conventions - the first argument designates an error, the second is the result value. So you'll have to pass `null` first:

```
…
this(null, data);
```